# ASP.NET Web Api Controller subfolder routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I’m going crazy here… this seems like a very simple task. First off, I know only the basics of the Web Api and MVC – so please don’t skewer me.

In the project I need to logically create controller subfolders (for organization purposes). I had a feeling it wasn’t as simple as I thought. I have the default route like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Which works as it should directly from the controllers folder in my project. I have added a subfolder in the controllers folder controllers/reports. I have searched quite a bit and just can't quite find a solution. How can I add a route that will direct to the subfolder.
I have tried:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ReportingApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/Reports/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

and:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ReportingApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/Reports/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "userunit" id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: Routing doesn't actually use the filesystem, it routes to controller actions.

Comment: But don't you at some point have to provide a path if a controller is in a subfolder? It doesn't just find it does it?

Comment: By convention, the framework looks for controllers in the `Controller` folder, but beyond that it's not looking at paths. Why do you need to create a subfolder for every controller? If you want, you can fiddle with routing to get the URLs just right, if that is what you are after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nevermind I'm an idiot... I left the default route in, removed the "Reports" in the url. It found the controller even though it was in a subfolder.

Comment: I've got a feeling this is gonna cause trouble down the line. What if you've got two identically named controllers separated by different namespaces due to the use of subfolders. This is simply an oversight in the WebApi design.